# Parse String with android

Tags: java, android, web-services

I have a reponse data from webservice with structure like this

```
string  tree/string host/int graph_id-string graph name
```

the data now is :

```
Default Tree
Default Tree/Localhost
Default Tree/Localhost /1- Memory Usage
Default Tree/Localhost /2- Load Average
Default Tree/Localhost /3- Logged in Users
Default Tree/Localhost /4- Processes
Default Tree/Localhost /13- Disk Space - \dev\sda1
Default Tree/Localhost /12- Disk Space - \dev\mapper\Vol
Default Tree/Smokeping Sites
Default Tree/Smokeping Sites/cnn.com
Default Tree/Smokeping Sites/cnn.com/sp4- cnn.com
Default Tree/Smokeping Sites/heute.de
Default Tree/Smokeping Sites/Test
Default Tree/Smokeping Sites/Test/google.de
Default Tree/Smokeping Sites/Test/google.de/sp2- google.de
Default Tree/Tree Item 2
```

Now I want to parse the data follow match this structure by using android ksoap.  But now I'm stuck how to do get exact the data.The data will be like this :

One Tree with a tree name have some host, one host with a host name will have some graph with graph id and graph name.

Please help me on this cause I'm newbie :D.

Any helps will be many thanks :D

Comment: You have this data stored in some variable and you want to parse it. Right?

Comment: I didn't get it, you want help for getting the String from SOAP web-service or for parsing the String after you got it? If the case is first one, kindly tell use more about the web-service like it's in .net or php etc.

Comment: I want to parse the string after got it from the webservice.The String will have the structure like this :One Tree with a  tree name have some host, one host with a host name will have some graph with graph id and graph name. The importtant with i want to get is follow by : Tree nam--> hosts--->grapgh_id----> graph name